# Keep dropdown in a sidenav open based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a menu using this tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown_sidenav.asp

I added this code to highlight currently selected link:

```
$("#sidenav a").each(function() {   
    if (this.href == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

How do I keep the dropdown open if a link in the dropdown is highlighted?
Just to add - my sidenav includes more than one dropdown.

Edit
My HTML:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //     this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

$("#sidenav a").each(function() {
  if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #212529;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a,
.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 11px 8px 11px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.dropdown-btn:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

a.active {
  background-color: #002f7c;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.current-menu-item {
  background: #33b5e5;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
  <a href="/users"> Users </a>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Computers</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/computers">Assigned</a>
    <a href="/computers/unassigned">Unassigned</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Monitors</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/monitors">Assigned</a>
    <a href="/monitors/unassigned">Unassigned</a>
  </div>

  <a href="/licenses"> Licenses </a>

  <a href="/reports"> Reports </a>
  <a href="/logs"> Logs </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your full code to snippet :D And since you have whole working example, you can figure it out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with jquery function `closest` you can select the closest parent element with the specific selector `$(this).closest(".dropdown-btn")` selects the closest parent with class "dropdown-btn".
so after selecting that, you can simulate click action on it or make it visible directly .

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //     this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

$("#sidenav a").each(function() {
  if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("dropdown-btn").css({display : "none"});
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-btn").css({display : "block"});
  }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 16%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #212529;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a,
.dropdown-btn {
  padding: 11px 8px 11px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.dropdown-btn:hover {
  background-color: #808080;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

a.active {
  background-color: #002f7c;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.current-menu-item {
  background: #33b5e5;
}

.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav" id="sidenav">
  <a href="/users"> Users </a>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Computers</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/computers">Assigned</a>
    <a href="/computers/unassigned">Unassigned</a>
  </div>

  <button class="dropdown-btn">Monitors</button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="/monitors">Assigned</a>
    <a href="/monitors/unassigned">Unassigned</a>
  </div>

  <a href="/licenses"> Licenses </a>

  <a href="/reports"> Reports </a>
  <a href="/logs"> Logs </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost solved my problem. The only thing I had to change was `$(this).closest(".dropdown-container").css({display : "block"});` since dropdown-btn is the parent of dropdown-container that I want to close.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it is possible to select previous element of the link container and then fire `click` event on it to call the function that toggles the dropdown menu. So, you could use the following snippet, just replace `$(this).attr("href") === "#1"` with `this.href == window.location.href`.

```js
$(".dropdown-btn").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
});

$(".sidenav a").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("href") === "#1") {
      $(this)
        .addClass("active")
        .closest(".dropdown-container")
        .prev(".dropdown-btn")
        .trigger("click");
    }
});
```

```css
/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width:100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
</div>
```